# Affected_rows returns negative -1 but insert

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, insert

I have the following PHP code, and when I execute it, affected_rows returns -1, but when I run a select in HeidiSQL, the data is in the table. Why does this happen?

```
$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
$estatus = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'estatus');
$larga = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'larga');
$corta = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'corta');
$fecha = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'fecha');
$usuario = $_SESSION['id'];
$query = 'INSERT INTO tarea(oportunidad_id, estatus, usuarioId, tareaTarea, fechaLimite, tareaCorta)'
       . 'VALUES(' . $id . ', "' . utf8_decode($estatus) . '", ' . $usuario . ', "' . $larga . '", "' . $fecha .
     '", "' . $corta . '")';
$con->query($query) or exit("Error: " . $con->errno . ": " . $con->error);
if ($con->affected_rows > 0) {
    echo 'Tarea agregada';
} else {
    exit($con->mensaje_error());
}
```

Comment: `Returns the number of affected rows on success, and -1 if the last query failed. `

Comment: Emmm I know, but seems that the query really don't fail because the data is inserted on the table.

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). I have serious doubts that `filter_input` is sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the recomendation :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ($result = $con->query($query)){
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        echo 'Tarea agregada';
    }
} else {
    exit($con->mensaje_error());
}
```

Try using num_rows instead of affected rows. And you are allowed to do $result = $con->query inside of this if statement, it does the same thing as `$con->query($query) or exit(...`

You can't ask the connection for the affected rows, you have to save the result as a variable and do `->affected_rows` on that result.

The query isn't failing, the way you check the query is failing

Comment: This is a way, but then when I should to use `affected_rows`?

Comment: affected_rows is for INSERTs, UPDATEs, REPLACEs and DELETEs. num_rows is for SELECTs.

Comment: That's the point. I want to use the affected_rows to validate if the INSERT is correct.

Comment: you can simply do `if($con->query("INSERT ...")){` then.

Comment: i down voted because this doesn't really answer the question